# Proving a set X is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If ($x_n$) is a sequence converging to a limit $L$, show that $X = \{x_n: n \in N\}$ is bounded.

My proof is as follows.

Let $\epsilon$ be a positive number.
Since $x_n \to L$, there exists $N(\epsilon)$ such that $n > N(\epsilon)$ $\implies$ $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$.
Set $M = \max(L-\epsilon, x_1, ..., x_N, ... |L+\epsilon|)$.
So, for all $x \in X$, $x \leq M$.
Thus $X$ is bounded.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 2):

You should set $M=\max\{|L|+\epsilon,|x_{1}|,...,|x_{N}|\}$. Usually we choose a concrete $\epsilon>0$ in this case, say, $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: So no need for absolute value around the epsilon? And with that correction is the proof correct?

Comment: Beware that you need two-sided bound, that is, $-M\leq x_{n}\leq M$ for all $n$, equivalently, $|x_{n}|\leq M$ for all $n$. Your method just has the upper bound, not the lower bound.

Comment: Since M is max('') and includes L+e, shouldn't |x_n| < M implicitly?

Comment: Okay, you may play the following game: $x_{1}=x_{2}=\cdots=x_{10}=-100$, $x_{11}=x_{12}=\cdots=10$, $L=10$, $\epsilon=1$, so $M=\max\{9,-100,-100,...,11\}=11$, does it follow that $|x_{n}|\leq 11$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof shows that the sequence is bounded above not bounded.

You need to show that there exists some positive $M$ such that $$|x_n|\le M, \text { for all } n\in \mathbb {N}$$